# Manipulating data.frame while using cycles and storing values in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, cycle

I have 2 codes that manipulate and filter (by date) my data.frame and that work perfectly. Now I want to run the code for not only one day, but for every day in vector:

```
seq(from=as.Date('2020-03-02'), to=Sys.Date(),by='days')` #.... 538 days
```

The code I want to run for all the days between 2020-03-02 and today is:

```
  KOKOKO <- data.frame %>%
          filter(DATE < '2020-03-02')%>%
          summarize(DATE = '2020-03-02', CZK = sum(Objem.v.CZK,na.rm = T) 
        
  STAVPTF <- data.frame %>% 
          filter (DATE < '2020-03-02')%>%
          group_by(CP) %>% 
          summarize(mnozstvi = last(AKTUALNI_MNOZSTVI_AKCIE), DATE = '2020-03-02') %>%
          select(DATE,CP,mnozstvi)  %>%      
          rbind(KOKOKO)%>%
          drop_na() %>%
```

So instead of '2020-03-02' I want to fill in all days since '2020-03-02' one after another. And each of the KOKOKO and STAVPTF created for the unique day like this I want to save as a separate data.frame and all of them store in a list.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `map` to loop over the sequence and apply the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map(s1, ~   data.frame %>%
          filter(DATE < .x)%>%
          summarize(DATE = .x, CZK = sum(Objem.v.CZK,na.rm = TRUE))
```

As this is repeated cycle, a function would make it cleaner

```
f1 <- function(dat, date_col, group_col, Objem_col, aktualni_col, date_val) {
     filtered <- dat %>%
          filter({{date_col}} < date_val)
     KOKOKO <-  filtered %>%
          summarize({{date_col}} := date_val,
          CZK = sum({{Objem_col}}, na.rm = TRUE) 
        
    STAVPTF <- filtered %>%        
          group_by({{group_col}}) %>% 
          summarize(mnozstvi = last({{aktualni_col}}),
            {{date_col}} := date_val) %>%
          select({{date_col}}, {{group_col}}, mnozstvi)  %>%      
          bind_rows(KOKOKO)%>%
          drop_na()
    return(STAVPTF)
}
```

and call as

```
map(s1, ~ f1(data.frame, DATE, CP, Objem.v.CZK, AKTUALNI_MNOZSTVI_AKCIE, !!.x))
```

where

```
s1 <- seq(from=as.Date('2020-03-02'), to=Sys.Date(), by='days')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer your question, if you would provide a minimal reproducible example. It's easy done with tidyverses [reprex packages](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/)

However, your KOKOKO code can be rewritten as simple cumulative sum:

```
KOKOKO = 
  data.frame %>% 
  arrange(DATE) %>%    # if necessary 
  group_by(DATE) %>% 
  summarise(CZK = sum(Objem.v.CZK), .groups = 'drop') %>% # summarise per DATE (if necessary)
  mutate(CZK = cumsum(CZK) - CZK)  # cumulative sum excluding current row (current DATE)
```

Even STAVPTF code can probably be rewritten without iterations. First find the last value of AKTUALNI_MNOZSTVI_AKCIE per CP and DATE. Then this value is assigned to the next DATE:

```
STAVPTF <-
  data.frame %>% 
  group_by(CP, DATE) %>% 
  summarise(mnozstvi = last(AKTUALNI_MNOZSTVI_AKCIE), .groups='drop_last') %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%    # if necessary 
  mutate(DATE = lead(DATE))
```